# How to make links appear only on mobile and not on desktop?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, mobile, navbar

Say I have a standard bootstrap navbar that collapses down on mobile. Currently everything in the desktop navbar appears on mobile. How do I make it so that say, "Contact Us" only appears on mobile and not on the desktop navbar?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the display classes. The below example will hide the `<li>` element on the medium break point and up.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/display/

```
<ul>
<li class="d-md-none"><a href="/contact">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```